# Sieve of Eratosthenes thinks all numbers are prime after 127

Tags: java, algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm running into problems with my Sieve of Eratosthenes. I wanted to write a Sieve that didn't require an array of all numbers up to the largest prime you want, instead just keeping track of each prime multiple as the Sieve reaches it. That means you don't have to do all the work up front, but can just determine the next prime when you need it. It would also be easy to add interface features like "find K primes starting at N". Here is the pseudocode:

```
Begin with current number set to 2
Loop:
    If prime queue is not empty:
        Peek at the top prime in the queue
        If current > top, we can move top to the next multiple
            Remove the top prime from the prime queue
            Increment top to its next multiple
            Re-add it to the queue
        If current == top, current is not a prime
            Increment current number to next integer
        If current < top, we've found a prime
            Break
Push current number onto prime queue
Increment current number to next integer
Return the new prime
```

So here's the problem: I correctly calculate the first 31 primes (up to 127), but after that it thinks *every* number is prime. I've put my code on Ideone -- I'm hoping it's some Java collections behavior, or a trivial bug, rather than the algorithm itself. I can't think of a reason the algorithm should break after a certain number of primes. I've confirmed manually that after 127, if the heap is properly ordered, my algorithm should recognize 128 as not a prime, but that's not what the code shows me.

Any suggestions?

http://ideone.com/E07Te

(I will, of course, increment by 2 (to skip all non-prime even numbers) once I get the basic algorithm working. I'll probably also make the Sieve an iterable.)

Comment: Vote to close: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: The idea is not new: [Melissa O'Neill's paper](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf)

Comment: @Daniel: I didn't expect it to be new, of course. It was novel and interesting to me, though ;)

Comment: @Oli: The linked code has print statements around the problem area. My description of the behavior was enough for someone to say "Aha" and give me the right answer. I included the summary of the algorithm for good measure. I had tested the algorithm, and suspected it was a Java language feature I hadn't accounted for or some obvious bug. And it was. I could have done more work, but I *didn't need to*.

Comment: @theazureshadow: That's exactly what makes this an inappropriate question for SO.  You should have stepped through your code line-by-line in the debugger to eliminate the possibility of an obvious bug *before* posting the question.

Comment: @Oli: I don't think it was *completely* unreasonable, but I'll certainly learn to use the jdb for next time. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is

```
top.multiple == current
```

in connection with

```
Integer current = 2;
Integer multiple;
```

There is a cache of `Integer`s with small absolute value, `-128` to `127`, if I recall correctly, so the comparison using `==` compares identical instances for values smaller than 128. But from 128 on, you get a new boxed `Integer` for `current`, and that is a different object than the one referenced by `top.multiple`.

Compare using `equals` or declare `int current;` to solve it.

And improve your algorithm, note multiples of each prime only from the prime's square.

Comment: That'll teach me to use operators on objects! I suspected it was some Java language feature that I hadn't accounted for (I'm writing some simple programs to learn Java.) Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: Yes, it's a gotcha. It would be easy to spot such things if they always did not do the intended thing, but with things like the small-`Integer` cache and interned `String`s, it's easy to fall into these traps.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to figure out why you could start crossing out at the prime squared. Of course: all the other multiples have already been crossed out (since they are all also multiples of smaller numbers than the prime).

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking your whole list:

Sieve heap after 31:
[[127:127], [11:132], [2:128]

You get to 132, which is > 128, and thus hit the `break;` before you check for 2*64.

Comment: It's a heap, after incrementing 127, the new top is `[2:128]`, that part works alright.